# Is the Ubuntu Mobile SDK available for Mac OS X or Windows?

Tags: windows, application-development, macosx, ubuntu-touch

I'm a mobile app developer. I code for Android and iOS on Mac OS.

I don't want to buy another computer just to code for Ubuntu Mobile.

Will the Ubuntu Mobile SDK be available for Mac OS or Windows?

Comment: You don't need to buy another computer, you can always use a virtual machine. Also you can install Ubuntu on your mac.

Comment: Agreed, Cmon Patryk your probably still sore from having to buy a mac to make iOS apps but Ubuntu runs on anything including your mac or a VM.

Comment: You shouldn't work full time on huge projects using a Virtual machine for the same reason why a developer should use more then 1 finger to type code. I think ubuntu needs to offer some more tools for other OS' or the amount of apps will be quite low ...

Answer (score 5):

There is no SDK preview available for other platforms other than Ubuntu at this point.

However, you can either:

- Install Ubuntu on a virtual machine and try the preview, or
- Manually install the Ubuntu QML components on another platform

The first should be relatively trivial to set up, whereas the second should in theory work, but it's not been tested and obviously not supported.